# How to detect/identify if device Lock Screen setting is set to None?

Tags: android, android-settings, android-security

I need to check before enabling my application if the device has no security defined on setting.

Can't have set: Pattern, PIN, Password and even Swipe.

Does anyone know a way to check if the lock screen setting is not enabled?

Alternately, can we check which of the above lock screen settings is enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use KeyguardManager - it's isSecureMethod() should return false in Your case. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html

Comment: isDeviceSecure or isKeyguardSecure does not returns TRUE in case Swipe is set.

Comment: This is possible only in Android 6.0 and above

Comment: @JonasOliveira how to check if security is set to SWIPE ?

Comment: @ralphgabb, I'm sorry but I don't know about the SWIPE. I'm not sure if there is a way to identify only the swipe.