# can i check if any security for lock screen active?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am looking for a plugin for cordova, which I can check if any security was set for the lock screen, e.g. a figure or a code or anything else

minimal target devices are Android and iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome on stackoverflow.

Here, you can't just ask like this, you have to do some research before.

I give you some help  for you'r futur research on cordova :

When you want to know if a plugin exist, you have to check first the official cordova website.

Then, if this not successful, you will search the native functonnality cause if there don't exist, plugin can't exist too.

So in you'r case i do this search : `android apps checking which lock screen set` and i found this : [How to detect/identify if device Lock Screen setting is set to None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194314/how-to-detect-identify-if-device-lock-screen-setting-is-set-to-none)

On this topic they are talking about KeyguardManager on android native code.

Next step : `google` **->** `cordova KeyguardManager` plugin and you can find this plugin : https://github.com/kitolog/cordova-plugin-screen-locker

Ok is only work on android but now, you can search alone the perfect plugin you need.

Have a nice day.

Comment: i had try to search an answer. i had serch for "cordova check if lock screen active" with non useful results. only how i can open the security settings.

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings
Documentation will help you, she is very nice

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a secure lock screen is configured, you can use the plugin cordova-check-screen-lock ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-check-screen-lock), [GitHub](https://github.com/ABarak64/Cordova-Screen-Lock-Enabled)).

On Android it checks whether a pattern, pass, or pin is set by checking [isKeyguardSecure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#isKeyguardSecure()) and [LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED).

On iOS, it [adds an item to the keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1401659-secitemadd) with [kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessiblewhenpasscodesetthisdeviceonly/), which only succeeds if a passcode is configured.